# Is there a function continuous on $\mathbb R$ but not on $\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity

We've been talking about continuity in my real analysis group, and I was wondering if there are any functions that are continuous on $\mathbb R$ , wherein I think my intuition lies, but which are NOT continuous on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: As stated, the question is trivial: knowing what a function does on $\mathbb R$ tells you exactly nothing about what it might do on the complement of $\mathbb R$.  But maybe you did not really mean "any function"...

Comment: Perhaps you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_permanence ?

Answer (score 7):

$$f(z)=\lfloor\Im(z)\rfloor{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: Could you please explain what that is?

Comment: @ZacharyF: It's the integer part of the imaginary part of $z$

Comment: @@ Zachary F) No explanation is needed ..Try yourself.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 It could well be the notation that is confusing. The imaginary-part function, for instance, I would write as $\text{Im}$, to be completely unambiguous.

Comment: @PatrickStevens yes, I've never seen the imaginary part function written that way before.

Comment: @PatrickStevens The main reason I started using $\Im$ is because that is what shows up when I type `\Im`; other alternatives are not as terse in TeX and I've since gotten used to it. Both forms are common. (Also it's always nice when I get a chance to give a good one-word answer.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $d(x)$ be any discontinuous function, say the Dirichlet function or the floor function.  Then $$f(a+bi) = d(b)$$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ (indeed, it's constant on any horizontal line) but discontinuous on $\Bbb C$.